# Select the maximum value from counted columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I  try to find the riskiest city according to state_of_health from a Person Table.

Person Table:

[image: Person Table Image]

We can assume that:

if state_of_health = true -> risky

if state_of_health = false -> risk-free

My query(I find counted values but I can not get the maximum value of them):

```
select  
    p.city,
    count(p.state_of_health)
from public."Person" p
where p.state_of_health = true
    group by city
```

My Output:

[image: Output Image]

Expected output:

city | count

New York    2

OR

Texas       2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
select p.city, count(p.state_of_health)
from public."Person" p
where p.state_of_health = true
group by city
order by count(p.state_of_health) desc
limit 1;
```

Note:  `state_of_health` looks like a boolean.  If so, it will not count just true values.  I think you want:

```
select p.city,
       count(*) filter (where p.state_of_health) as num_risky
from public."Person" p
where p.state_of_health = true
group by city
order by num_risky desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: state_of_health can take only two values 1- "risky" 2-"risk-free" should I represent it with a boolean or character varying ?

Comment: I know this is another question but I'm confused about that too.

Comment: @AssSoonAsPossiblee . . . It really doesn't matter, although if you use a boolean I would recommend a name such as `is_risky_health` to make it clear that it is a flag.